# Angstrom start-up processes [beaglebone]

Tags: startup, beagleboard, angstrom-linux

I have a RFID module attached to my beaglebone and reading ID tags with a python code. Now, I want my python code to start running in the background directly when I login to my beaglebone without any commands . Just like adding a program to start-up programs in windows. When you login to your windows account, those programs start instantly. Do you have an idea how this can be done?

Regards

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a new file in /lib/systemd/system/ (rfidreader.service in my example) with content like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start Python RFID reader

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/...Python script path.../
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python rfidreader.py
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then execute the following command to install the service:

```
systemctl enable rfidreader.service
```

To start the service, you can either reboot or execute:

```
systemctl start rfidreader.service
```

To check if the service is running and get the latest outputs from the script:

```
systemctl status rfidreader.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how nodejs application is running on port 3000 of the board and you can implement you module the same way. I think it's part of init process.

http://www.softprayog.in/tutorials/starting-linux-services-with-init-scripts
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-do-i-automatically-start-a-program-at-start-up-102154/